# German equivalent for "look and feel"

Tags: english-to-german, expression, phrase-request, letter, handwriting

I’m drafting a ‘handwritten’letter to a good friend who has been studying German for the past three years.  I’m using my computer to ‘write’ the letter, using the “Mistral” font in 16 point size.  The letter will be sent to him via the U.S. Postal Service in an addressed envelope bearing a U.S. postage stamp.

In my letter I’m telling my friend about the “Mistral” font.  The problem I’m having is explaining in German  how close “... the look and feel ...” of the Mistral script typeface is to the Sütterlin script font.  I’m writing him to tell him that, to me,  using the Mistral  typeface for
‘handwritten’ text in letters makes that text so much easier to read and understand than ‘handwriting’ it (i.e., typing it) in the Sütterlin font.

I have searched in both my contemporary Langenscheidt and mid-1950's Cassells dictionaries under the headwords “look” and “feel” for a word  or equivalent German phrase that can be used for the English phrase “... the  look and feel of ... “, but my search has been without success.

If  this contemporary English phrase doesn’t have a German equivalent should I then use the literal English–>German translation “... *das Ausehen und das Fühlen von* ...”?

Comment: The title and the first half of the question are misleading. I think you should leave out most of the backstory and choose a title that mentions “look and feel”.

Comment: There's no direct equivalent, as you can see e.g. by the translation examples on [linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=look+and+feel): Many translators are lazy and just keep "Look & Feel" as foreign expression. "Anmutung" is dated, the natural way would probably be to use a completely different expression, but you didn't mention the sentence you want to translate. And today, nobody uses Sütterlin, few can write it, many have trouble reading it.

Comment: Not part of your question but: The [Mistral font family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistral_(typeface)) is certainly not like [Sütterlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sütterlin). Did you mean "cursive"?

Comment: @Carsten: I agree and won't rewrite the introduction, but the title can be edited with sufficient rep.

Comment: @Stephie: I have been for some time very familiar with the Sütterlin typeface both in printed form and written form, and I can both read it and write it.  And I had earlier downloaded the Sütterlin font on my computer  in order to be able to type it.  I have the lesson book and practice book of Harald Süß's "Deutsche Schreibschrift" lettering guide; I'm well beyond Sütterlin, and am now learning "Die Offenbacher Schrift".  In addition I have a copy of Kai Dinstel's

Comment: @Stephie: (con't) delightful little version of "Max und Moritz" (written by Wilhelm Lüsch") which is printed in Sütterlin typeface.  And by the way, thank you so very much for putting me on to J. Nefflen's "Der Vetter aus Schwaben Oder Schwabenbrauche aus dem Leben Gegriffen".  I now have a beautifully bound copy with photo-facsimile pages from what I would like to believe is the original 1842 printed text -- with the glossary that you had told me about !

Comment: The first half of the question is rather distracting, as it is not related to what the question at all.

Comment: @Gerhardh:  Instead of editorializing and criticizing my writing style, might it actually be much more helpful to me if you would provide me with an answer my question?

Comment: "The letter will be sent to him via the U.S. Postal Service in an addressed envelope bearing a U.S. postage stamp." - I'm confused. Is this aspect of the letter supposed to belong to the letter's "look and feel"?

Comment: @dirkt Using it untranslated is not lazy. It's the right thing to do. It is a technical term, and there is no German equivalent. In German, "look and feel" is used as a Fachbegriff just like in English.

Comment: @dirkt In this context, "Anmutung" is not dated, it's a technical term.

Comment: Ich bin auch irritiert von der Zusammenstellung "easy to read" mit "Sütterlin". Kann es sein, dass Sütterlin hier nur ein spezifischer Schriftname ist, der nicht das darstellt, was man gemeinhin unter Sütterlinschrift versteht? Was die Briefmarken usw. mit der Frage zu tun haben erschließt sich mir auch nicht.

Comment: Judging from the answers given, here is a related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/39531/1696).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally consider terms as *look and feel* somewhat overrated, and assume, they would not be half as popular if they did not consist of snappy monosyllabic words which are known to everyone. Especially in respect to something abstract as a font I see a long way to go to achieve *feeling*.

Actually matching nouns exist (even if somewhat out of mainstream)

- Anmutung (my favourite, since it leaves the reception path open)
- Air (wiktionary gives as synonyms: *Art*, *Stil*, *Aussehen*, *Wesen*)
- Design (even if somewhat restricted to optical channel)

I don't consider *Wesen* a good translation, since this implies the real properties and not the observed ones, which I would associate with *look and feel*.

A flexible and not too poetic phrase is:

> ... vermittelt den (denselben) Eindruck ...

Comment: Darf ich "das Design" ergänzen?

Comment: @guidot:  Actually, I believe "Wesen" (the essence) comes very close in meaning to the English expression, "the look and feel"

Comment: @К.КеллоггСмиф: "Essence" is not the same as "look and feel". "Essence" depicts intrinsic properties, while "look and feel" merely describes exterior properties.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: How about if |I use "das Erscheinungsbild" in my letter instead of "wesen", i.e. "... das Mistral Schrift hat das Erscheinungsbild von Sütterlin Schrift?"?  Do you think perhaps that word would be a better fit?

Comment: @dirkt: Vielen Dank reur: "Linguee" comment.  It was right on the money for what I was looking for!

Comment: @К.КеллоггСмиф: Yes, that would be a lot better. "Look and Feel" could be translated as "Optik und Haptik", even if you can't really "feel" such things. Or perhaps "Optik und Verhalten". Oh, and it is "die Schrift" and "die Schriftart", so "Die Mistral Schriftart hat..."

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis:  Thank you for your comment.  You are quite correct in your literal translations of the English semi-slang phrase "look and feel".  But "Erscheinungsbild" is exactly the German word I was looking for when I wrote this question.

Comment: @kirkt:  The English expression "the look and feel" is colloquial English, not "semi-slang" as I termed it above.

Comment: "Anmutung" sounds like from a fairy tale book, it's today's language

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't translate this.

"Look and Feel" has found its way into the German language already. It's an established term. There is no equivalent short translation.

Answer (score 4):

I would propose:

> optischer Eindruck (literally: visual impression)

The word "optisch" translates the "look" and "Eindruck" the "feel".

Comment: The feel of e.g. a GUI is really how it "feels", i.e. how it behaves when you touch it, move it (with the mouse or finger or trackpad, etc.), what happens when you hover over it, etc. That is not just an **optical** impression, that is a **haptical** impression too. So "optischer Eindruck" doesn't quite get it. Some GUIs even use vibration or other pure haptical impressions (ever tried an Apple Watch or iPhone? Yoi can really feel some of the actions)

Answer (score 2):

I propose

> Anmutung

or

> Erscheinungsbild

as possible terms, the former giving a bit of a sophisticated, almost antiquated air, while the latter is certainly neutral enough to use in your context.