# Was ist eine "Anmutung" eines Betriebssystems?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In einer Werbepublikation (Printmedium als Zeitungsbeilage) von Google kann man folgenden Absatz finden:

> Das erste androidbasierte Gerät kommt auf den Markt: das HTC Dream, in Deutschland ab Anfang 2009 als T-Mobile G1. Dieser und andere Hersteller beginnnen, für ihre Marken eigene **Anmutungen** von Android zu entwickeln.

Für Betriebssysteme kenne ich den Begriff **Variante**, **Derivat** oder **Portierung**. Den in der Kunst selten verwendete Begriff [*Anmutung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anmutung) habe ich in diesem Zusammenhang noch nie gehört.

Handelt es sich um einen bloßen Übersetzungsfehler, oder ist *Anmutung* eine mir bislang entgangene Fachbezeichnung im Kontext der Androidentwicklung? Welche Bedeutung könnte gemeint sein?

Answer (score 13):

Während die von Dir angegebenen Termini, *Variante*, *Derivat* und *Portierung* (mit Ausnahme von Variante) den technischen Vorgang beschreiben, vermute ich stark, dass hier auf die andere Erscheinungsform, die damit typischerweise verbunden ist, abgehoben wird. Ich glaube außerdem, dass es sich um die Übersetzung dessen handelt, was typischerweise mit

> Look and Feel

bezeichnet wird. Trotz des ungewohnten Begriffs halte ich *Anmutung* für eine gute Übersetzung.

Comment: Ich glaube auch, dass es sich um einen Versuch, so etwas wie *Look & Feel* zu übersetzen, handelt. Und einen erstaunlich treffenden. Das Wort wäre mir nicht eingefallen.

Comment: "Trotz des ungewohnten Begriffs halte ich Anmutung für eine gute Übersetzung." - ich hatte als Muttersprachler bis zum Lesen deiner Erklärung keine Vorstellung, was damit gemeint sein könnte. Das spricht nicht für die Übersetzung. (Mir ist allerdings der Begriff *Anmutung* auch in anderen Kontexten noch nie begegnet, was wohl zu der Verständnisschwierigkeit beiträgt.)

Answer (score 3):

Nach einer kurzen Recherche denke ich, dass der Begriff *Anmutung* zwar nicht oft, aber doch hin und wieder im Zusammenhang mit der App-Entwicklung für Smartphones verwendet wird.

Meiner Ansicht nach ist damit nicht das (eigentliche) Betriebssystem gemeint, sondern nur die jeweilige *Oberfläche*. Oft findet man hierzu, dass die Hersteller von Android-Geräten ihre eigenen *Herstelleraufsätze* entwickelten ([Quelle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(Betriebssystem))):

- HTC Sense
- Sony UI
- Touch Wiz UI (Samsung)
- Optimus UI (LG)
- Emotion UI (Huawei)

Aber natürlich ist *Herstelleraufsatz* ein sehr sperriger, technischer Begriff. Aus technischer Sicht bleibt aber das eigentliche Betriebssystem unverändert, lediglich die *Oberfläche* (z. B. der Launcher) wird grafisch verändert.

Und bei der **grafischen** Gestaltung kommt tatsächlich der künstlerische Aspekt zum Tragen, der oft mit dem Begriff *Anmutung* in Verbindung gebracht wird. So geht es darum, dass die Symbole in der Benachrichtigungsleiste ein einheitliches Designkonzept haben, also alle Symbole die gleiche Anmutung. Oder dass alle Oberflächenelemente wie Schaltfläche, Auswahlboxen usw. dem gleichen Design, eben der Anmutung folgen.

Somit kann man meiner Ansicht nach zusammenfassend sagen, dass diese *Herstelleraufsätze für die Android-Oberflächen* tatsächlich ihre eigene **Anmutung** haben - vor allem, wenn es um eine kurze, prägnante Bezeichnung in einer Werbepublikation geht.